Trouble with url in AJAX
When i use route name for url it display this error:
POST http://127.0.0.1:8000/admin/product/%7B%7B%20route('product.store')%20%7D%7D 404 (Not Found)
Instead i have to use /admin/product/store
------------------------------------------------------------------------
main.js
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('.form').on('submit', function(e){
        e.preventDefault();
        $.ajaxSetup({
            headers: {
                'X-CSRF-TOKEN': $('meta[name="csrf-token"]').attr('content')
            }
        });  

        $.ajax({
            processData: false,
            contentType: false,
            type: 'POST',
            datatype: 'JSON',
            data: $(this).serialize(),
            url: "{{ route('product.store') }}",
            // url: '/admin/product/store'
            success: function (result) {
                if (result.error == false) {
                    showToast();
                } else {
                    alert('Thêm lỗi vui lòng thử lại');
                }
            },
            error: function(jqXHR, textStatus, errorThrown) {
                console.error('AJAX error:', textStatus, errorThrown);
            }
        });
    });
    // }
});

web.php
Route::prefix('admin')->group(function () {
    Route::controller(ProductController::class)->prefix('product')->group(function () {
        Route::get('/list', 'list')->name('product.list')->can('list-product');
        Route::get('/add', 'add')->name('product.add')->can('add-product');
        Route::post('/store', 'store')->name('product.store');
        Route::get('/edit/{id}', 'edit')->name('product.edit')->can('edit-product');
        Route::put('/update/{id}', 'update')->name('product.update');
        Route::delete('/delete/{id}', 'delete')->name('product.delete')->can('delete-product');
    });
});

add.blade.php
@extends('admin.layout.main')

@section('header')
    <script src="/ckeditor/ckeditor.js"></script>
@endsection

@section('content')
    <form action="" method="GET" class="form">
        {{-- @csrf --}}
        <div class="card-body">
            <div class="row">
                <div class="col-md-6">
                    <div class="form-group">
                        <label for="menu">Tên Sản Phẩm</label>
                        {{-- old(): Trả về giá trị của trường "description" mà người dùng đã nhập trước đó,
                        để nếu validate error thì sẽ ko cần nhập lại --}}
                        <input type="text" name="name" id="name" value="{{ old('name') }}" class="form-control"  placeholder="Nhập tên sản phẩm">
                    </div>
                </div>

                <div class="col-md-6">
                    <div class="form-group">
                        <label>Danh Mục</label>
                        <select class="form-control" name="menu_id">
                            <option value=""></option>
                            {{-- @foreach($menus as $menu)
                                <option value="{{ $menu->id }}">{{ $menu->name }}</option>
                            @endforeach --}}
                            {!! App\Helpers\Helper::recursiveSelectMenu($menus) !!}
                        </select>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>

            <div class="row">
                <div class="col-md-6">
                    <div class="form-group">
                        <label for="menu">Giá Gốc</label>
                        <input type="number" name="price" value="{{ old('price') }}"  class="form-control" >
                    </div>
                </div>

                <div class="col-md-6">
                    <div class="form-group">
                        <label for="menu">Giá Giảm</label>
                        <input type="number" name="price_sale" value="{{ old('price_sale') }}"  class="form-control" >
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>

            <div class="form-group">
                <label>Mô Tả </label>
                <textarea name="description" class="form-control">{{ old('description') }}</textarea>
            </div>

            <div class="form-group">
                <label>Mô Tả Chi Tiết</label>
                <textarea name="content" id="content" class="form-control">{{ old('content') }}</textarea>
            </div>

            <div class="form-group">
                <label for="menu">Ảnh Sản Phẩm</label>
                <input type="file" class="form-control" name="file" id="upload">
                <div id="image_show"></div>
                <input type="hidden" name="thumb" id="thumb">
            </div>

            <div class="form-group">
                <label>Kích Hoạt</label>
                <div class="custom-control custom-radio">
                    <input class="custom-control-input" value="1" type="radio" id="active" name="active" checked="">
                    <label for="active" class="custom-control-label">Có</label>
                </div>
                <div class="custom-control custom-radio">
                    <input class="custom-control-input" value="0" type="radio" id="no_active" name="active" >
                    <label for="no_active" class="custom-control-label">Không</label>
                </div>
            </div>

        </div>

        <div class="card-footer">
            <button type="submit" name="submit" id="uploadButton" class="btn btn-primary">Thêm Sản Phẩm</button>
        </div>
    </form>
@endsection

@section('footer')
    <script>
        CKEDITOR.replace('content');
    </script>

@endsection

Does anyone know the problem is ?

Your Blade expression {{ route('product.store') }} isn't parsed when it's in a .js file
